# Homeomorphism between two spaces

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that

$$X :=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1 \}\cup \{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}: -1\le x \le 1\}$$

$$Y :=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1 \}\cup \{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}: -1\le x \le 2\}$$

Are the above sets homeomorphic?

Comment: 1. You need to include what you tried and where you got stuck. 2. $\leg$ is an unknown command. Use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html to find the symbol you need. Oh, and braces need to be escaped as `\{ \}`

Comment: How can I fixed

Comment: I attempted an edit, hopefully it's what you intended. Feel free to either ask me in case it isn't.

Comment: Where is your editing

Comment: Under what topology?

Comment: Subspace with of usual topology do you another way to explain it without using connected

Answer (score 1):

Draw these sets and figure out the maximum number of points one can remove from $X$ so that it is still connected.  This number plus $1$ will be the maximum number of points that one can remove from $Y$ so that it is still connected (Why?).

From this, you can conclude that $X \ncong Y$ since any homeomorphism $\phi:Y \rightarrow X$ should be able to restrict to a homeomorphism $\psi:Y \setminus S \rightarrow X \setminus \phi(S)$ for any subset $S \subset Y$.

Comment: This is a nice and intuitive answer. +1